# 500 internal unknown error when batch request Google drive API permission via Postman

Tags: google-drive-api

[image]

[image]

I followed the example here:https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch

Curious why it is an internal error?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**As seen in the first photo**

[image]

Selecting `JSON` in the marked place is mandatory.

This solution will work